# Как сравнить 2 тхт файла и удалить повторы: удалить строки из первого файла которые содержат мыла из второго

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем доброго дня, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать сравнение и удаление.
Формат первого файла

```
Y.Turner@Hotmail.Com:Yvette Turner
Kelliekelly@Hotmail.Com:Kellie Kelly
Hades2056@Hotmail.Com:James Gillam
Peter.Garrad@Tesco.Net:Carl Garrad
```

Формат второго

```
Hades2056@Hotmail.Com
Peter.Garrad@Tesco.Net
```

То есть во втором файле чисто мыльники, цель-удалить строки из первого файла которые содержат мыла из второго.
К сожалению питон только начал изучать, подскажите за что зацепиться.

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что вы не знаете как это написать на конкретном языке, или же вы не можете придумать алгоритм?

Comment: А вы не для спамеров работаете ли?

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись одним циклом:

```
import csv

fn1 = r'C:\Temp\.data\616780_1.txt'
fn2 = r'C:\Temp\.data\616780_2.txt'

with open(fn1) as f1, open(fn1 + '.new', 'w') as fout, open(fn2) as f2:
    mails = set(f2.read().splitlines())
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in csv.reader(f1, delimiter=':'):
        if not row[0] in mails:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

C:\Temp.data\616780_1.txt.new:

```
Y.Turner@Hotmail.Com:Yvette Turner
Kelliekelly@Hotmail.Com:Kellie Kelly
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_1 = open('1.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
file_2 = open('2.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')

array = []
for email in file_1:
    if email.split(':')[0] not in file_2:
        array.append(email)

str = ""
for email in array:
    str += email
    str += '\n'

file_3 = open('3.txt', 'w')
file_3.write(str)
```

Спасибо undeadter

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы удалить строки из `1.txt` файла, которые начинаются на e-mail из `2.txt` файла:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path
from fileinput import FileInput

prefixes = tuple(email+':' for email in Path('2.txt').read_text().splitlines())
with FileInput('1.txt', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        if not line.startswith(prefixes):
            print(line, end='')  # keep
```

#### Результат

```
Y.Turner@Hotmail.Com:Yvette Turner
Kelliekelly@Hotmail.Com:Kellie Kelly
```